# Question on logic rather than specific programming issue

Tags: database, architecture

If not here, what would be the right place to ask this question? I am creating a web application which will host questions and answers covering different topics. A user should see list of questions and can attempt to answer the one they like. The user however should not see the question they have already answered in the list of questions.

The stack I intend to use is `Express`, `Node`, `Mongo`.

Should I incorporate the logic in application which maintains list of questions answered by user and not present those questions to the user why excluding the answered questions when querying the database? My concern is this solution might be difficult to scale and could degrade performance.

In summary, what might be the right way to implement a use case which shows the users only a subset of values from a global set which the user has not already seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to store the questions as they are and store the users as well.

Then, store the relations between user and question in a table/document called user_answers or something of the like.

You do need to store these relations *somehow*, which, if nothing's wrong, then you can simply store it in the database. And I suggest that you could do this for the time being and if it turns out to be scaling badly in terms of performance, particularly searching them, then you will be able to store a file for each user at a file location uniquely identifiable via the user, a hash or something and whenever the user's answers are needed, then simply load that file server-side and add the question ids present there into a filter.

So, you can actually store these as files and it would become as easy to load them as opening a file, but if I were you, I would not do this right away. I would simply use the db features already present and once this becomes unsolvable, then I would migrate them into files.

This means that any coding that you work should be as much agnostic to the whereabouts of the location of answers per user and, if possible that should be specified at a single place, so, if you need to migrate this, you will have an easy task in terms of coding and a wait upon the values being actually moved.

Comment: so I should maintain a record of questions answered by a user (say question id) in a database to begin with and use filters of database (eg find where `id `not equal to `a` && `id` not equal to `b` and ... so on? The filter would not be an issue if say there filter contains over 100 ids?

Comment: @ManuChadha it should not be a problem if you do not have an extremely large amount of questions. My assumption was that you would not have 100 000 questions in total or above. If you have potential of having more than 100 000 different questions, let me know and I will provide further ideas for refinement.

Comment: @ManuChadha because in that case you can load the questions in an unfiltered manner into memory, loop them and exclude from the response if they were already answered. But this further tweak should only be done if you still have performance issues.